How to scrape results from newman-reporter-htmlextra and SeleniumBase .html reports into a ready made docx/pdf template?
I am trying to combine both test results from API Testing (Postman) and UI Testing (SeleniumBase) into an 'Overall QA Report'. Currently, I am doing it manually by screenshotting multiple results pages from both of the reports and then pasting it into the Overall QA Report template. I would like to try and automate this process (if possible).
I tried looking into BeautifulSoup and Scrapy (with some help from ChatGPT and YouTube) but didn't manage to get it working. Here's my idea:
SBase Report
Newman Report
Overall QA Report Template
Overall QA Report with screenshots of SBase Report attached
Overall QA Report with screenshots of Newman Report attached
Any help or ideas for the implementation would be much appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.
I tried to use Scrapy and BeautifulSoup but the scripts seem not working (most likely wrong identification of the elements) both are returning empty results
Scripts:
# BS4 Script :
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parse_pytest_html_report(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'html.parser')

        # Find all table rows containing test results
        test_results = soup.find_all('tr', class_='col-name')

        # Extract information from each test result
        """for test_result in test_results:
            # Test name is usually contained within the first <a> tag inside the <td> with class 'col-name'
            test_name = test_result.find('td', class_='col-name').a.text

            # Test status is usually contained within the <span> tag with class 'col-result'
            test_status = test_result.find('td', class_='empty log').span.text

            # Extract more information as needed...
            
            # Process the extracted data (store in a data structure, print, etc.)
            print(f'Test: {test_name}, Status: {test_status}')"""
        print (test_results)

parse_pytest_html_report('sbase_report.html')


# Scrapy Script :
import scrapy

class SeleniumBaseTestReportSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'seleniumbase_test_report'
    start_urls = ['sbase_report.html']  # Replace with the path to your SeleniumBase report file

    def parse(self, response):
        # Extract information from test results
        test_results = response.css('col-name')

        for test_result in test_results:
            test_name = test_result.css('.test-name::text').get()
            test_status = test_result.css('.test-status::text').get()

            # Process the extracted data (store in a data structure, print, etc.)
            yield {
                'Test': test_name,
                'Status': test_status
            }


Sample Sbase and Newman reports can be found here : https://github.com/mastafadhil/sbase_newman_reports

I can generate newman report by htmlextra. How to generate UI SeleniumBase html?

@Bench Vue you may use "--dashboard --html=report_name.html" when running your seleniumbase for example "pytest test_script.py --dashboard --html=report_name.html --reruns=3"
